# Create a pattern to replace all script sources

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I create a pattern that replaces all the scripts sources in a php document with another string?

For example we have the `$haystack = '<script src="oldscript.js"></script>';`

And we should do it like this `$haystack = preg_replace('/src="[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,250}"/', 'myscript.js', $haystack);`

But this does not work. I am doing something wrong ? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Unless you are just hung up on why a regex didn't work, the largest common validation denominator makes your regex reduce to `(?<=src=")[^"]+(?=")` and the length is futile.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to include dot in your regex and also add `src="..."` in replacement:

```
$haystack = preg_replace('/src="[\w.]{1,250}"/', 'src="myscript.js"', $haystack);
```

Comment: Yes you are right, it was the dot that was breaking the pattern.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this better solution:

```
$re = "/(<script.*src=)(\"|')(.*)('|\")/";
$str = "<script type=\"javascript\" src='oldscript.js' ></script>\n<img src='test.jpg' />";
$subst = "\1\2myscript.js\4";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/sL8bL0/1)

Comment: i have said better not best.